# SQL - combine multiple rows in to a single as a list

Tags: sql, merge

How to combine/merge multiple rows into a single rows as a list in SQL.

[original Scenario:]

[image]

[Required Scenario:]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with? The answer depends on it.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides `ROW_NUMBER()` function to achieve the above

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [column1] ORDER BY [column1]) > 1
            THEN ''
            ELSE CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR)
        END [column1],
        [column2]
FROM <table>;
```

**EDIT :** use of `STUFF()` function

```
select 
       [column1],
       [column2] = stuff(
                          (select DISTINCT ' '+[column2] from <table> where [column1] = t.[column1] for xml path('')),
                          1,1, ''
                    )
        from <table> t group by [column1]
```

Result :

```
column1 column2
1       Value 1 Value 2 Value 3
2       Value 4
3       Value 5 Value 6
```

Comment: this gives me separate rows in column2 for each value in column1, but I want single row in column2 for each value in column1.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Yogesh For your help !!

I have used the below query and it is working fine for me and displays the data as required[required Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNAyq.png):

```
    Select distinct ST2.SubjectID, 
    substring(
        (
            Select CHAR(10) +ST1.StudentName  AS [text()]
            From dbo.Students ST1
            Where ST1.SubjectID = ST2.SubjectID
            ORDER BY ST1.SubjectID
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Students]
From dbo.Students ST2
```